# How to avoid down-casting when return types are not known at compile time?

Tags: c++, linked-list, abstract-syntax-tree, downcast

Suppose I have a abstract base class called `Node`.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() {
        leftChild = NULL;
        rightChild = NULL;
    };

    Node * leftChild, *rightChild;

    void attach(Node * LC, Node * RC) {
        leftChild = LC;
        rightChild = RC;
    };
};
```

I also have multiple functions (of which I'll include two for simplicity but in reality this could be any number).

```
float add(float a, float b){return a+b;}
bool gt(float a, float b){return a>b;}
```

For each function there is an associated class. The first is as follows.

```
class BinaryFunction1 : public Node
{
public:
    BinaryFunction1() {
    };

    float(*)(float, float) addition(){
        return add
    };
}
```

The second is below.

```
class BinaryFunction2 : public Node
{
public:
    BinaryFunction2() {
    };

    bool(*)(float, float) greaterthan(){
        return gt
    };
}
```

In main I would like to execute something like the below as a way of creating a linked list in the hopes of building an abstract syntax tree.

```
BinaryFunction1 testBinaryFunction1();
BinaryFunction2 testBinaryFunction2();

testBinaryFunction1.attach(&testBinaryFunction2, &testBinaryFunction2);

dynamic_cast<BinaryFunction2 *>(testBinaryFunction1.leftChild)->greaterthan()(2.0, 4.0)
```

The `dynamic_cast` is really ugly and I see it tripping me up further down the road. Is there a way to avoid this and get rid of it entirely.

As far as I can see `Node * leftChild, * rightChild` is really the problem as I believe this is where the implicit down-casting happens. I am unsure how to declare these pointers if I don't know what their types will be at compile time.

Comment: Have `Node` specify the interface with `virtual  bool(*)(float, float) greaterthan() = 0;`. or ex. `virtual  bool(*)(float, float) greaterthan() { return nullptr; }` or `virtual  bool(*)(float, float) greaterthan() { throw Node::exception_greather_then_not_found(); }`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's not extendable though. You have to change the base class for each new operation. And a polymorphic solution that isn't extendable is immediately suspicious.

Comment: I wonder if [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) could help here.  You could have a `get` function in the base class that is a template and returns the function pointer from the derived type.  This lets you set the relationship at compile time so you don't have to cast.

Comment: AST woes are frequently remedied by the visitor pattern. Have you taken a look at `std::variant`/`std::visit` yet?

Comment: I have and I've also considered the visitor pattern although I'm not actually sure how to implement it here. Some instruction on that would be really helpful. I have also looked at std::variant but I somewhat consider that cheating... maybe I shouldn't. @MaxLanghof

Comment: @JakeDyson Why is it cheating?

Comment: I also think you would want to abstract the concrete types and function signatures away here. A `BinaryFunction` should have an `apply` operation that takes two `TypedValue`s and returns a `TypedValue` (this could be done with `std::variant` too, but then the set of types in the AST is hardcoded everywhere). The question you should ask yourself is "what should happen when the AST is invalid on the type level (`bool` passed where `float` was expected)". Assuming the AST is built from runtime input, there is no compile-time way to prevent a user from inputting invalid stuff.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning which may not apply here but it feels like something similiar. How would I go about using std::variant? Even a starting point would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would look something like this:

```
using TypedValue = std::variant<int, float, bool>;

using BinaryFunc = std::function<TypedValue(TypedValue, TypedValue)>;

struct Node
{
public:
    Node() {
        leftChild = nullptr;
        rightChild = nullptr;
    };

    virtual ~Node() = default;

    Node * leftChild, *rightChild;

    void attach(Node * LC, Node * RC) {
        leftChild = LC;
        rightChild = RC;
    };

    virtual TypedValue evaluate() = 0;
};


struct BinaryFuncNode : public Node
{
    BinaryFuncNode(BinaryFunc func) : Node(), binaryFunc(func) {}

    BinaryFunc binaryFunc;

    TypedValue evaluate() override
    {
        return binaryFunc(leftChild->evaluate(), rightChild->evaluate());
    }
};

struct ConstantNode : public Node
{
    ConstantNode(TypedValue val) : Node(), value(val) {}

    TypedValue value;

    TypedValue evaluate() override
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

I don't know what exactly you want to do with the function pointers you are currently trying to return, but it's probably got to do with evaluating an expression. That concept can go into the `Node` interface and can be implemented by each concrete type of node. That requires specifying a return type though, and that's not something known at the `Node` level. In fact, it's presumably unknown at compile-time in general - invalid user input can obviously not lead to compile-time errors, it will have to lead to run-time errors. `std::variant` is a good match here (but limits you to a compile-time set of types, which is probably sufficient).

We can then define e.g.

```
// Function that can only add integers (throws otherwise)
BinaryFunc addI = [](TypedValue lhs, TypedValue rhs)
{
    return std::get<int>(lhs) + std::get<int>(rhs);
};
```

and use everything together like this:

```
int main()
{
    auto cnode = std::make_unique<ConstantNode>(10);
    auto bfnode = std::make_unique<BinaryFuncNode>(addI);
    bfnode->attach(cnode.get(), cnode.get());
    return std::get<int>(bfnode->evaluate());
}
```

(Note that polymorphy requires pointers or references!)

Play around with it here: https://godbolt.org/z/GNHKCy

Comment: Thank you this is absolutely fantastic!